# How to delete a specific managedObject from core data.

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My app makes 2 kinds of GET requests to a restful API. The objects they return are the same except for 1 value. Both have that value present, just 2 different strings. Each returned object is stored in core data. I need to be able to discriminately delete core data objects that have 1 of the 2 string values. Every example I've seen has the object in a tableView so they just identify it by [indexPath.row]. Mine is not.

Here is code.

```
// Can't seem to specify an entity to delete other than with the coredata objectId.
func removeKeyHolders(){
    let moc = Stack.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
    let people = self.fetchMakerPerson()
    for person in people {
        if person.beaconInRange == Constants.Parse.targetStringKeyBeacon {
            moc.deleteObject(person)
            do {
                try moc.save()
                print("DELETED KEYHOLDER???")
            } catch {
                print("Unable to delete keyHolder")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we get more details? What errors are being thrown?

Comment: In the app there is a ViewController with a UIImageView, a UILabel that has some text, and a UIButton with a phone number as text. All of these are populated by one ManagedObject subclass object. There is also a refresh button that makes a GET request that pulls down only the most recent object to have a specific string in one of their Parse columns. Before that request is made, I need to delete any other object that may be stored with that same 'beaconInRange' string.

Comment: No errors are being thrown, but the object is not being deleted. I have another function that deletes the whole store and that works. I just can't make it happen for this specific object.